# Asynchronously map JSX in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have async function that basically fetches a list from the backend, and I would create a html list on the FE with those elements.
For that I want to do a map on that list. The problem is that since it's the result of a async function, it seems that I need add some details.

Based on my [searches](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-async-functions-with-array-map-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=The%20map%20function,-The%20map%20is&text=An%20async%20version%20needs%20to,async%20before%20the%20function%20does.&text=And%20second%2C%20it%20needs%20to,the%20results%20in%20an%20Array.), I should do something similar to this:

```
const listItems = await Promises.all( podcastList.map(
      (podcast) =>{
      <ListItem value = {podcast} />}
      ));
```

However, I get the error:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (21:20)
```

The remaining functions are:

```
function ListItem(props) {
  return <li>{props.value}</li>;
}

async function podcast_list() {
  let podcast_list;
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
  const res = await fetch('/list_podcasts', { method: 'GET',headers});
  podcast_list = await res.json();
  console.log(podcast_list);
  return podcast_list
}
podcastList = podcast_list();
```

Comment: Based on the code shown, you don't want to use `async` *as part of the `.map()` operation*.  There's nothing asynchronous happening there.  You just need to `.map()` over the *result* of your asynchronous operation, the awaited result of `podcast_list()`.  Where do you ever call that function?  How do you await its result?  Where is `podcastList` defined and what is its value?  What does any of this have to do with React?

Comment: Everything David said. Also: if you _did_ decide to use `Promise.all` at some point (where it was necessary) it would be, well, `Promise.all` not `Promises.all`.

Comment: @David I've just added some info, and removed the async in the map. Any more suggestions? I still have the same error. Well, the react part is that this error is happening in my first original react app. I just thought it could be important to know.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. as I mentioned in another comment `podcast_list` returns a promise because it is an async function so you'll need to add `const podcastList = await podcard_list()` in another async function or `podcast_list().then(data => {...}`. (Sadly [top-level await](https://caniuse.com/?search=top%20level%20await) has only _just_ been adopted by the _very latest_ versions of the major browsers so I would be wary about using it just yet - but you should be able to later this year as it gathers momentum.)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: `podcast_list()` returns a promise, not an array of promises.  Await it with `await` or follow it with a `.then()`.  There's nothing that sets it apart from any other function that returns a promise, just like the two promises you `await` within that function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSX can't be returned from a component asynchronously. Separate your raw data from your JSX--`await` the request for the raw data, set state to trigger a rerender once the data arrives, then build the JSX UI.

```js
// Mock for demonstration
fetch = () => Promise.resolve({
  json: () => Promise.resolve([
    "some podcast",
    "some other podcast",
  ])
});
//

const ListItem = ({value}) => (
  <li>{value}</li>
);

const Podcasts = () => {
  const [podcasts, setPodcasts] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/list_podcasts")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setPodcasts(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {podcasts.length ? (
          <ul>
            {podcasts.map((e, i) =>
              <ListItem key={i} value={e} />)
            }
          </ul>
        ) : <div>Loading...</div>
      }
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Podcasts />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Use `camelCase` in JavaScript, not `snake_case` and don't forget to add a unique `key` attribute to list items.

Comment: Please, bear with me... In the last .then, I added `console.log(podcasts)`. This prints a correct list.
I've also added a `console.log("2nd print:"+podcastList)` just below, and outside, of  the useEffect, and it prints `2nd print:[]`.

I never go away from the loading message.

Comment: Are you setting the podcasts array to state properly, and then using the `.length` of that state to figure out whether to render loading or the podcasts? I suggest debugging by logging your `podcasts` array just above the `return (JSX)`. If it never changes from `[]`, then you're probably not triggering the `setPodcasts(data)` properly. `useEffect` capture group should be empty (`[]`) so it runs only once on the first render.

Comment: Thanks ;) After much debugging, I finally managed to solve it.

Answer (score -2):

You don’t need to await on maps when rendering JSX elements. Just:

```
const listItems = podcastList.map((podcast) => <ListItem value={podcast} />)
```

Comment: `podcast_list` still returns a promise though so you'll need to take that into consideration.

Comment: That’s because you have to await when getting the podcast_list, but not when mapping trough it.

Comment: You can podcast_list?.map, so that you prevent of mapping while getting the data